# How to use asp.net mvc web form to make button closer to another button?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, razor

[image]I have a working button and its built inside the form on my View, but the UI does not look good and need some help in position the button closer to Upload button. Here is my logic below on View.cshtml;

```
   @using (Html.BeginForm("Browse", "Week", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data", @id = "upload" }))
    {
        

        @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create", routeValues: new { }, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "modal-link btn btn-primary" })



        <input type="file" id="fileUpload" name="upload" class="btn-primary" required style="display:none;" />
        <label for="fileUpload" id="button" class="btn btn-primary">Upload</label>
        <input type="submit" name="extract" class="btn-primary" required style="display:none;" />

       
    }
    @using (Html.BeginForm("ExportToExcel", "Week", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
    {

        <div>
            <input type="submit" value="Extract" class="btn btn-primary" />
        </div>
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Do this for center under:

```
<style>
.closer {
 margin-top: 0px;
}
    </style>
<input type="submit" class="closer" value="Extract" class="btn btn-primary" />
```

Do this for inline:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Browse", "Week", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data", @id = "upload" }))
    {
        

        @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create", routeValues: new { }, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "modal-link btn btn-primary" })



        <input type="file" id="fileUpload" name="upload" class="btn-primary" required style="display:none;" />
        <label for="fileUpload" id="button" class="btn btn-primary">Upload</label>
        <input type="submit" name="extract" class="btn-primary" required style="display:none;" />
       
    }
    @using (Html.BeginForm("ExportToExcel", "Week", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
    {
<input type="submit" value="Extract" class="btn btn-primary" />
    }
```

Comment: below or after the form itself? that is right after the button of Extract?

Comment: Tell me what two button?

Comment: I see this: <input type="file" id="fileUpload" name="upload" class="btn-primary" required style="display:none;" />
        <label for="fileUpload" id="button" class="btn btn-primary">Upload</label>
        <input type="submit" name="extract" class="btn-primary" required style="display:none;" />

Comment: Basically the upload button has its own logic and its working, now i want to create Extract button closer with space in between to Upload button allow position

Comment: Can you do a screenshot it make it easier to see.

Comment: Ok i see it is now closer, but i do need controller and method name for that button, have a look at my Razor carefully. How do then make a change for that? Now the button is closer but need that method

Comment: I have now attached the UI of this from the topic as image

Comment: Do you what it centered underneath or line with the others

Comment: Show me an example, maybe i can understand, because i need that logic for the Razor, i have a method that call export to excel function and download the file.

Comment: Remove the div from <input type="submit" value="Extract" class="btn btn-primary" />
Look above. Iforgot about the razor. Try it above

Comment: The button is closer, the problem now its not calling controller, it has not action in another words

Comment: Try what I posted.

Comment: i have tried its not working, button position is fine, but its not calling "ExportToExcel"

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Browse", "Week", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data", @id = "upload" }))
    {
        

        @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create", routeValues: new { }, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "modal-link btn btn-primary" })



        <input type="file" id="fileUpload" name="upload" class="btn-primary" required style="display:none;" />
        <label for="fileUpload" id="button" class="btn btn-primary">Upload</label>
        <input type="submit" name="extract" class="btn-primary" required style="display:none;" />

       
    }
    @using (Html.BeginForm("ExportToExcel", "Week", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
    {

        
            <input type="submit" value="Extract" class="btn btn-primary" />
        
    }
```

Comment: I missed a bracket.

Comment: Can I see a screenshot of this?

Comment: It is the same but without the div tags **_the div tag is what is putting it on a new line_**